# How to properly set makfile to compile different related files?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Hi I have some of the small programs, each of them will be compiled and run individually.

I was planning on using target specific variables to make the different programs, since it will be inherited recursively by target's prerequisites. Thus I could keep the dependency structure of compiled targets, and make the most use of duplicated commands.

The following is the current makefile:

```
# Variables =====================================================================================
PHONY           = 
# Main*****************************************
LEX_FILE    = wc.l
BISON_FILE  = yacc.y
BISON_OUT   = $(subst .y,,$(BISON_FILE)).tab.c $(subst .y,,$(BISON_FILE)).tab.h
LEX_OUT     = $(subst .l,,$(LEX_FILE)).yy.c
CFLAGS      = -g -lfl
# Flex ==========================================================================================
$(LEX_OUT):$(LEX_FILE) $(BISON_OUT)
    flex --outfile=$@ $<

PHONY += lex_clean
# Bison =========================================================================================
$(BISON_OUT):$(BISON_FILE)
    bison -d $<

PHONY += bison_clean
# Run ===========================================================================================
run.out:$(LEX_OUT) $(BISON_OUT)
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $(word 1,$^) $(word 2,$^) -o $@
run_lex.out:$(LEX_OUT)
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $(word 1,$^) -o $@
run:run.out
    ./$<
run_lex:run_lex.out
    ./$< $(BISON_OUT)

PHONY += run run_wc
# Clean =========================================================================================
clean:
    -rm *.out *.yy.c *.tab.h *.tab.c

PHONY += clean
# PHONY =========================================================================================
.PHONY: $(PHONY)
```

Now the different would only be the `LEX_FILE` and `BISON_FILE`, others would be based on these files.

The building process are basically the same, except some of them will build only flex or bision.

Thus I would like to ask if there is a good way for makefile to do this??

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You could also generate your `Makefile` using [cmake](http://cmake.org/), and you could use alternative building automation tools like [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/) or use [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html)

Comment: @basilestarynkevitch Hi, thanks a lot!! I've read the gnu make manual, and the example you posted, so the basic idea would be saving different makefiles, and use `make -f` option to do the different build right?? That is a way, and could I further ask if there is possibility to make it inside one makefile??

Comment: @basilestarynkevitch Hi I added my makefile lol

Comment: It's almost certainly not going to work to use target-specific variables.  You may have missed this absolutely crucial line in the docs: _As with automatic variables, these values are only available within the context of a target’s recipe (and in other target-specific assignments)._  That means that target-specific variables **CANNOT** be used in _prerequisites_.  They can only be used inside recipes.

Comment: @madscientist Yah I saw that, thus I would like to ask if there is a possible way of doing what I want. Since the actual building process are highly similar with different input files, the most significant differences are the input files. Without writing multiple makefiles (since the duplicate building process), would there be possible to build different targets??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# $@  表示目标文件
# $^  表示所有的依赖文件
# $<  表示第一个依赖文件
# $?  表示比目标还要新的依赖文件列表
# Variables =====================================================================================
PHONY           = 
# Main*****************************************
proj        = main
ifeq ($(proj),wc)
    LEX_FILE = wc.l
else ifeq ($(proj),ab)
    LEX_FILE    = lex.l
    BISON_FILE  = yacc.y
else
    LEX_FILE    = lex.l
    BISON_FILE  = yacc.y
endif
BISON_OUT   = $(subst .y,,$(BISON_FILE)).tab.c $(subst .y,,$(BISON_FILE)).tab.h
LEX_OUT     = $(subst .l,,$(LEX_FILE)).yy.c
CFLAGS      = -g -lfl
# Flex ==========================================================================================
$(LEX_OUT):$(LEX_FILE) $(BISON_OUT)
    @echo $(BISON_FILE)
    @echo $(BISON_OUT)
    flex --outfile=$@ $<

# Bison =========================================================================================
$(BISON_OUT):$(BISON_FILE)
ifneq ($(BISON_FILE),)
    @echo $(BISON_FILE)
    bison -d $<
endif

# Run ===========================================================================================
$(proj).out:$(LEX_OUT) $(BISON_OUT)
ifneq ($(BISON_FILE),)
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $(word 1,$^) $(word 2,$^) -o $@
else
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $(word 1,$^) -o $@
endif

run:$(proj).out
    ./$<

PHONY += run run_wc
# Clean =========================================================================================
clean:
    -rm *.out *.yy.c *.tab.h *.tab.c *.s

PHONY += clean
# PHONY =========================================================================================
.PHONY: $(PHONY)
```

and

```
make proj=wc run
```

or

```
make proj=ab run
```